# jqGrid filter toolbar filters out null values in grid data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use several jqGrids in an application and noticed what seems to me to be an odd behavior when enabling the filter toolbar.  I need to have the toolbar use a wildcard match (i.e., "contains").

However, when I set a grid up and some of the data used to load a grid has null values for certain columns, the grid will filter those values out by typing "null", "nu", "u", "l", "ll", etc. in the toolbar field for the column.  This happens when the default search for the filter is "cn" (contains).

This behavior does not happen when the default search is set to "eq" (equals), e.g., none of the combinations above will display any rows in the grid.

I've set up a fiddle at

https://jsfiddle.net/parramorej/ejnrtocw/

to illustrate the issue.  I'm loading a local data set into the grid with some of the values being null.  The default search is "cn", i.e.,

```
$("#test1").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    autosearch: true,
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter: true,
    defaultSearch: "cn"
}
```

and you can see the behavior by typing "null" into the toolbar fields with null column values.  If the default search is "eq", it does not occur.

Is this an intentional feature in jqGrid or a bug?  If it's a feature, is there an option to disable it with having to specify exact matches when filtering?

Thanks in advance...

Screenshot examples:

[image: Before applying date field filter]

[image: After applying date field filter]

Comment: The jqGrid version being used is 4.6.0.  I've verified that this still occurs in v4.7.1.  The jQuery version being used is 1.10.4.  In our application environment, the behavior occurs in both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 11 (IE 11 is the official version for users for the application but we mostly use Chrome in testing.)

Comment: You should write **all information in the text of the question**. You can click on "edit" link below your question and modify the text. About your question. First you should never fill the grid using `addRowData`, use `data` parameter instead: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ejnrtocw/45/. About your main problem: you didn't wrote any test case. **Which data you filter and in which column?** If would be more correct to use *formmaters*. For example `formatter: "number"`. It will force displaying 0 on null, undefined or empty string ("") input value.

Comment: I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork. The problem which you describe should not exist in the current version (4.13.1) of free jqGrid for `formatter: "number"` or `formatter: "integer"` (one can use `template: "number"` or `template: "integer"` in free jqGrid).

Comment: I looked for the edit link and completely missed it, otherwise, I'd have edited the original question... thanks.  :-T We've started using data to load the grids, but this was an older example.  As far as a test case went:  "you can see the behavior by typing "null" into the toolbar fields with null column values".  Also, for formatters, I'll try that and see.  We don't want to display a "0" if the string is undefined, null, or empty, though.

Comment: Definitely thank you for the feedback - it's been very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome! **Could you describe exactly one test case?** What you want to type in the filter for some column and which results you expect to have?

Comment: I tried to implement filtering in free jqGrid very flexible. In general you can have **any behavior**. I just don't understand, which behavior you need and in which column (for which type of data).

Comment: Np... I've added screenshots illustrating the original grid with data loaded (1st screenshot), then applying a filter to the Date column using "null" (2nd screenshot).  I was expecting to not have any rows returned.   but the three rows with the date value as null are returned.  If I change defaultSearch: "cn" to defaultSearch: "eq" in the grid definition, then I get the behavior that I was expecting, i.e. no rows appearing for those filter values.