# Custom Filter records in Free-jqgrid 4.15.4

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have one question regarding custom filters in free jqGrid 4.15.4. I want to implement a search functionality where if I select 'less than but not null or empty' filter then it should show only rows of records which column isn't null or empty. I am able to create custom filter which gives 'is null' or 'isn't null' from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441826/free-jqgrid-a-custom-filter-rule-for-empty-and-not-empty).
But when I tried to create for mine requirement, I wasn't able to figure out what operator I have to use for 'less than but not null or empty'.

for example, I have used this code sample to create custom filter:

```
 customUnaryOperations: ["lne"],
 customSortOperations: {
           lne: {
                operand: "<!=''",
                text: "less but not empty",
                filter: function (options) {
                    var v = options.item[options.cmName];
                    if (v !== undefined && v !== "") {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The above operator I've used in search option toolbar.

```
searchoptions: {
                     searchOperators: true,
                     sopt: ['eq', 'lt', 'gt','lne'],
                 }, search: true,
```

Meanwhile, I don't want to use  **formatter: "integer"** (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086398/jqgrid-filter-toolbar-filters-out-null-values-in-grid-data)) as this only assigns 0 to all null record column cells, and still visible in records whenever one selects **'less than'** filter .

For reference, I've created one [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x3fger4z/7/) which consists of the requirement and two images for more clarity. So, Can anyone help me out on this? I hope I'vent re-asked this again.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Grid_With_NoFiltersIN_SalaryField]

[image: Grid_with_Filter_InSalary_ButEmptyRecords]

Comment: In a nutshell, how to discard Highlighted rows(2nd image, where salary column is empty for 2 persons) when search using filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the filter could be like the following

```js
customSortOperations: {
    lne: {
        operand: "<!=''",
        text: "less but not empty",
        filter: function (options) {
            var v = options.item[options.cmName];

            if (v !== undefined && v !== "" &&
                    parseFloat(v) < parseFloat(options.searchValue)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/x3fger4z/17/

Comment: First of all wanted to thank you Oleg, for your awesome help. This is the exact operator I was looking for.  Where I missed to improve myself was `parseFloat(v) < parseFloat(options.searchValue)`. Would you mind if I ask about v ? I was getting the element values in v.