# Date "less but not empty" custom search in free-jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free-jqgrid 4.15.4 for showing the data. There i have a need to search date column with `Date less but not empty` filter, but it is not filtering correctly. In result it gives me date which are greater than searched date.

Below code is used for custom filter in date column:

```
customSortOperations: {

dlne: {
                operand: "<!=''",
                text: "Date less but not empty",
                filter:function (options) {
                    var p = this.p, iCol = p.iColByName[options.cmName], cm = p.colModel[iCol],
                        newformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.newformat ?
                                cm.formatoptions.newformat :
                                $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.newformat"),
                        srcformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.srcformat ?
                                cm.formatoptions.srcformat :
                                $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.srcformat"),
                        fieldData = $.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, srcformat, options.item[options.cmName]),
                        searchValue = $.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, newformat, options.searchValue);
                    var retFData = convertD(fieldData), t = new Date(retFData);
                    if ((retFData.getFullYear() < searchValue.getFullYear()) && (retFData.getMonth() < searchValue.getMonth()) && (retFData.getDate() < searchValue.getDate())) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
           },
}
```

The `convert` function that I am using for converting string into date format, is written below:

```
function convertD(dateField) {
var date = new Date(dateField),
    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
// year= (date.getFullYear())

var retVal = [day, mnth, date.getFullYear()].join("/");
return retVal;
}
```

I have taken the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705227/custom-filter-records-in-free-jqgrid-4-15-4) and made some changes but seems no avail. So requesting community to help on this.

Comment: Could you provide **the demo** with some test data, which reproduce the problem? The exact format of your input data could be important. For example, you can get some jsfiddle demo, which I created before and to modify it so that one can see the problem.

Comment: Additionally I don't understand the meaning of the line `var retFData = convertD(fieldData), t = new Date(retFData);`. If you use `srcformat` and `newformat` options of `formatter: "date"` corresponding the input and display data format, then `fieldData` and `searchValue` will be already `Date` objects. See the code and the demo from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29676941/315935).

Comment: Hello @Oleg, (here)[https://jsfiddle.net/6rub7svz/1/] is the **js fiddle demo** with some test data. Here you will see some date columns are empty. What I want is to create a custom filter which is able to select rows without selecting empty rows. The operator here is **date less but not empty** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of `dlne` could be fixed to for example the following:

```js
dlne: {
    operand: "<!=''",
    text: "Date less but not empty",
    filter: function (options) {
        var p = this.p, iCol = p.iColByName[options.cmName], cm = p.colModel[iCol],
            newformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.newformat ?
                    cm.formatoptions.newformat :
                    $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.newformat"),
            srcformat = cm.formatoptions != null && cm.formatoptions.srcformat ?
                    cm.formatoptions.srcformat :
                    $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.srcformat"),
            fieldData, searchValue;

        // the exact condition to test for "empty" depend on the format of your data
        if (!options.item[options.cmName]) {
            return false; // ignore empty data
        }

        fieldData = $.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, srcformat, options.item[options.cmName]);
        searchValue = $.jgrid.parseDate.call(this, newformat, options.searchValue);
        return fieldData.getFullYear() < searchValue.getFullYear() ||
            (fieldData.getFullYear() === searchValue.getFullYear() &&
                fieldData.getMonth() < searchValue.getMonth()) ||
            (fieldData.getFullYear() === searchValue.getFullYear() &&
                fieldData.getMonth() === searchValue.getMonth() &&
              fieldData.getDate() < searchValue.getDate());
    }
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/51vfn4k9/11/

Comment: Hello @Oleg, While the above answer works for other columns, there is one column which date is coming in following format: "/Date(1547145000000)/". So that is failing the result grid. Could you please tell how to change the format of that date column?

Comment: Also, $(this).jqGrid("getGridRes", "formatter.date.srcformat") giving date format is in d-m-Y, which I want in dd/mm/yy (ex: 27/04/2019).

Comment: @Chandan: Why you don't post the demo with your test data, like I asked you? Instead of that you posted my original demo. Could you modify my demo and include **your test data**, which includes some non-empty dates and empty dates too? Additionally it's important to use `srcformat`, which corresponds the format of your data. Try https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/51vfn4k9/16/, which uses `formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: "d/m/Y" }`. The input data having the format `"/Date(1547145000000)/"` will be detected automatically and processed ignoring `srcformat`.

Comment: If I correclty understand you then it seems you haven't seen the fiddle that I posted earlier. Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/40ckdxs1/ which includes test data almost similar to what I have used in my project. The format option `formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: "d/m/Y" }` is in my original project but there this format `"/Date(1547145000000)/"` is I guess causing the issue.

Comment: @Chandan: Your last demo uses `formatoptions: {srcformat:"d/m/Y", newformat: "d/m/Y" }`, but the input data don't corresponds the `srcformat`: see `"2007-09-06"` and `"2007-10-03"` mixed with dates like `"12/10/2007"`. You should use **one** format, which corresponds `srcformat`. Moreover if **another formatted data** (like "/Date(1547145000000)/") causing the issue then why you don't include the data in the demo? Just post the demo, which can be used to reproduce the problem, which you have.

Comment: Boss, thanks for the answer, it was my overthinking/discrepant data which stretched the thread. :) but now its all sorted. so accepting the answer. Thanking you again. Here is two demo links in case any one want to see them: https://jsfiddle.net/40ckdxs1/2/ https://jsfiddle.net/6rub7svz/1/