# Free-jqGrid: Dynamically Setting Search input According to Custom Selected Operand

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using free jqgrid, I implemented custom search operands using "customSortOperations: {}", I want to change the search field input to a select when I choose one of my custom operands, is there a way to do that? if not is there an event that fires when the operand is chosen to listen for it and implement my custom search field change? here is a sample of how I'm using "customSortOperations: {}"

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    customSortOperations: {
        tst: {
            operand: "T",
            text: "Test",
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You posted only short fragment of your code. Thus, I'm not sure that I full understand your problem. To use new custom search operand you should define `filter` method inside of `customSortOperations.tst` and include the operation `"tst"` inside of `searchoptions.sopt` of column definition in `colModel`. If you want to use the new operation `"tst"` as default searching operation then the operation `"tst"` should be the first in `searchoptions.sopt` array. See for example https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/f3gLde6m/2/ created for [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52705954/315935) for more details.